# HSTS header (strict-transport-security) is not getting always. (sometimes getting and sometimes not)

Tags: java, spring-boot, iis, hsts

I configured the IIS to get the HSTS header. When I tried to verify using the curl command. I got the header sometimes and sometimes I'm not getting it.

[In the below image you can see I accessed the same site using the curl command. The first time I got the HSTS header and the second time I didn't get it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/05SFQ.png). Any help would be appreciables

Comment: "I configured the IIS to get the HSTS header", how? It is very easy to choose a wrong approach.

Comment: Configured by adding HTTP Response headers and URL rewrite

Comment: Hi, has the problem been solved? If you think my reply is helpful to you, you can mark it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think this may be a problem with your configuration, you can install the following steps to configure HSTS:

Open the Internet Information Services (IIS) Manager via Start → Administrative Tools → IIS Manager.

[image]

Click on HTTP Response Headers.

[image]

Click on Add... in the Actions panel.

[image]

Enter the following values in the Add Custom HTTP Response Headers:

**Name: Strict-Transport-Security**

**Value: max-age=31536000**

[image]